# Finding the infimum of summable sequences in a decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, frame-theory

Let $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^2$ denote the canonical orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Put $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^4 = \{e_1, e_2, e_1-e_2, e_1 + e_2\}$. Clearly we have a representation of $e_1$ in terms of $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^4$. I am interested in finding $$m = \inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^4 |c_k|: e_1 = \sum_{k=1}^4 c_kf_k\right\}.$$ Clearly $m \leq 1$ since we can take $c_1 = 1$ and $c_2 = c_3 = c_4 = 0$. However, I believe that $m = 1$. To show this assume that we have $$e_1 = \sum_{k=1}^4 c_kf_k,$$ for some $\{c_k\}_{k=1}^4$. How can I show that $$\sum_{k=1}^4 |c_k| \geq 1?$$

Comment: The $e_1$ coefficient on $\sum_{k=1}^4 c_kf_k$ is $c_1+c_3+c_4$, and it's also $1$, because the sum is $e_1$. So by triangle inequality, $$\sum_{k=1}^4 |c_k|\geqslant c_1+c_3+c_4=1.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it!

You can first solve the linear system of equations: that will let you find the coefficients for linear combinations of your generators that result in $e_1$.

For that, first solve for $e_1$, for example $e_1=f_1$, and then solve the homogeneous equation to see all possible solutions.

I got the following solution for the homogeneous equation:
$$0 = \alpha (f_1 + f_2 - f_3) + \beta(f_1 - f_2 - f_4) \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}.$$

Now note that if $e_1 = \sum_{c=1}^{4} c_i f_i$ then we have that we can equivalently suppose that the $c_i$ are of the form:
$$c_1 = 1 + \alpha - \beta, \\
c_2 = \alpha - \beta, \\
c_3 = -\alpha, \text{ and}\\
c_4 = - \beta.$$

Now you can replace each $c_i$ by these expressions and minimize over $\alpha$ and $\beta$ instead.

However, note that
$$|c_1| + |c_2| + |c_3| + |c_4| \geq \\
 (1 - |\alpha| - |\beta|) + |\alpha - \beta| + |\alpha| + |\beta|
= \\
1 + |\alpha - \beta| \geq 1$$
which in combination with the fact that the sum is $1$ when $\alpha=\beta=0$ proves your affirmation is true.